# GCP - Restore Stored Procedures in a Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to recover the deleted procedure/s from a dataset that were accidentally deleted. I know I can recover tables but I can't seem to find anything related to stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Datasets [cannot be restored once deleted](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#deleting_a_dataset). So any information you have there will be lost once you delete it.

However, there might be a way of recovering a procedure by searching in Logs Explorer. To do so, run the following query:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
"CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE $NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET" 
severity="INFO"
```

As per the timestamp, if you know when a procedure was last launched or created you could search around that timestamps. (This is not strictly needed but it can save you a lot of query processing time).

After that, hopefully you will be able to find logs [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzbJV.png). If you expand the log payload, in `serviceData` field you will find [the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vui4d.png) in the `query` subfield.